# In Express router, what is the best way to specially handle "random" urls that aren't handled by anything else?

Tags: express

Say I was making a URL shortener service, and I want it to be able to make urls like [domain]/xf6B2sT.  But I also want to be able to have "normal looking urls," whether the pages are static or dynamic, and if a normal page is routed, it won't continue to look for ones of this compact format.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you had an algorithmic way to tell whether a URL was a shortened URL or not without looking it up in your database and without comparing to all the regular site URLs.  That algorithm just has to be something that allows you to examine a URL and immediately determine whether it's a shortened URL or not.  If not, you send it to a router for your site URLs and if it doesn't match there you return a 404.  If it does match the format for a shortened URL, then you look it up in the database and go from there.

The algorithm could be whatever you want.  It could be that all site URLs have one level of path:  `http://yourdomain.com/site/home` or it could be that all shortened URLs start with some magic character like an `x` that no site URLs will ever start with.  There's an infinite number of possible algorithms you could invent.  The point is you need to be able to quick look at a URL with some Javascript in your middleware and determine which it is without looking up anything in a database.